# How can elasticsearch objects be boosted based on date or score

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

For example, if something has a higher favorites_count I want it to be more relevant, or if it is updated more recently it is more relevant. Is there a way to do this? This is different than the standard boost functionality, because these fields don't contain keywords, they contain a numeric value.

Comment: Similar question answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091365/is-it-possible-to-boost-newest-items-using-elasticsearch-foqelasticabundle

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `function_score` to boost your doc base on a custom formula.
Refer here (`script_score` section) for more details:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

You can also use decay functions to boost recently created documents over older results, refer here for sample:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/0-90-4-released/

Then refer here for a more complex sample of using script to calculate score:
http://web.archive.org/web/20170107105531/https://jontai.me/blog/2013/01/advanced-scoring-in-elasticsearch/