# ElasticSearch Java Boost on Date

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am currently boosting on url, title, and description as follows:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(term,"title", "description","url").field("title", 1.75f).field("url", 1.55f).field("description", 1.35f);
```

I would like to further add boosting to documents created more recently (I have a postDate field mapped as date).

I found this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208124/how-can-elasticsearch-objects-be-boosted-based-on-date-or-score) pointing to a [legacy ES Doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/0-90-4-released/) which refers to gaussian decay. However, I cannot seem to find this in the current Java [Api doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html).

How would I add a boost to my QueryBuilder for more recently created (postDate) documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the function score query:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

The following code gives a hint to what you could use:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(term,"title", "description","url").field("title", 1.75f).field("url", 1.55f).field("description", 1.35f);
FunctionScoreQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(qb);
builder.add(ScoreFunctionBuilders.exponentialDecayFunction("postDate","14d"));
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question based on the link above, does the "14d" mean everything inside of 14 days gets a boost? Where day 1 gets a higher boost than day 13? And everything after 14 decays exponentially (backend of bell curve)?

Comment: Hm, the way I understood things get less boost up to 14 days and after 14 days there is no boost anymore.