# elasticsearch query how do i give priority to newer documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents stored with their created date:

```
{
  created: 1394822042952
}
```

I want to boost newer ones. What type of query do I use?

Thanks.

Comment: See previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091365/is-it-possible-to-boost-newest-items-using-elasticsearch-foqelasticabundle