# ElasticSearch : boost popularity AND date

Tags: elasticsearch

as in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/boosting-by-popularity.html I want to boost my search result by their popularity.

BUT I also want to boost the more recent.

I had the idea to combine this request with the one of RobMaters : [Is it possible to boost 'newest' items using elasticsearch? (FOQElasticaBundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091365/is-it-possible-to-boost-newest-items-using-elasticsearch-foqelasticabundle)

I have the feeling it's kind of weird to boost the popularity in some way (the fiels value factor function) ant the date in another (directly in the range query) --> Is there a "good" way to do it?

(if it is usefull I use the java api)

Comment: I can imagine a `bool` query with several `should`s: several using `boost` for `range` queries and another one using the approach for popularity boost. Why weird?

Comment: Just because the "boost" concept is not applied in the same way for the date and the popularity...

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old now, but for anyone else that encounters this I would suggest taking a look at this resource: https://www.voxxed.com/2014/12/advanced-scoring-elasticsearch/

You can apply a `function_score` to the query and provide functions which can boost based on a field's value. A `gauss` function is a good bet for dates, and a `field_value_factor` is probably good for a popularity measurement. There is nothing stopping you from combining both as well.